# Converting API JSON data to a Swift struct

Tags: json, swift, codable

I am using Swift for the first time and I'd like to be able to process some info from an API response into a usable Swift object.

I have (for example) the following data coming back from my API:

```
{
    data: [{
       id: 1,
       name: "Fred",
       info: {
           faveColor: "red",
           faveShow: "Game of Thrones",
           faveIceCream: "Chocolate",
           faveSport: "Hockey",
       },
       age: "28",
       location: "The Moon",
    },{
        ...
    }]
}
```

In swift I have the `data` coming back from the API. I get the **first object** and I'm converting it and accessing it like so:

```
let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: Any]
let dataParentNode = json["data"] as! [[String:Any]]
let firstObject = dataParentNode[0]

let _id = firstObject["id"] as? String ?? "0"
let _name = firstObject["name"] as? String ?? "Unknown"
```

This is fine until I want to start processing the sub-objects belonging to the first object so I came up with the following `struct`s to try and make this cleaner.

**Please note - I don't need to process all of the JSON data coming back so I want to convert it to what I need in the structs**

```
struct PersonInfo : Codable {
    let faveColor: String?
    let faveShow: String?
}

struct Person : Codable {
   let id: String?
   let name: String?
   let info: PersonInfo?
}
```

When I take this:

```
let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: Any]
let dataParentNode = json["data"] as! [[String:Any]]
let firstObject = dataParentNode[0]
```

and then try to convert `firstObject` to `Person` or `firstObject["info"]` to `PersonInfo` I can't seem to get it to work (I get `nil`).

```
let personInfo = firstObject["info"] as? PersonInfo
```

Can anyone advise please? I just need to get my head around taking API response data and mapping it to a given struct (with sub-objects) ignoring the keys I don't need.

Comment: `let personInfo = firstObject as? PersonInfo`, `firstObject as? PersonInfo` is nil, because `firstObject` isn't cartable as a PersonInfo, it's a Dictionary at best. `let personInfo = PersonInfo(faveColor: firstObject["faveColor"] as? String ?? "Unknown color", faveShow: firstObject["faveColor"] as? String ?? "Unknown show")`

Comment: @Larme - sorry that was a typo. `firstObject` is the first result in the array from `data` in the JSON so it should be: `let personInfo = firstObject["info"] as? PersonInfo` in my OP

Comment: `let personInfoDict = firstObject["info"] as? [String: Any]`, and `let personInfo = PersonInfo(faveColor: personInfoDict["faveColor"] as? String ?? "Unknown color", faveShow: personInfoDict["faveColor"] as? String ?? "Unknown show")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `decode(_:from:)` function of `JSONDecoder` for this:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
    let decoded = try decoder.decode([String: [Person]].self, from: data)
    let firstObject = decoded["data"]?.first
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Even better you can add another struct to you model like this:

```
struct PersonsData: Codable {
    let data: [Person]
}
```

And map your JSON using that type:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
    let decoded = try decoder.decode(PersonsData.self, from: data)
    let firstObject = decoded.data.first
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

**Update**: Your Person struct might need a little change, because the id property is integer in your JSON.

So, it will end up like this:

```
struct Person : Codable {
   let id: Int?
   let name: String?
   let info: PersonInfo?
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for this. This was the answer for me. I'd tried doing something similar but still got an error. Turns out I didn't note a potential variation in the API response which I needed to cover. All working now and much cleaner code!